# Is "quite unique" correct?

Tags: word-usage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are the rules regarding absolute modifiers too absolute?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44566/are-the-rules-regarding-absolute-modifiers-too-absolute)

Reading the sentence below, written on **The Telegraph**, it can notice the phrase *quite unique*.

> I never imagined a situation when I would write this line, but I think
>   I need the help of a Welsh speaker. There is something ***quite unique***
>   happening with the Wales team and I need a name for it.

Considering that ***unique***, from the Latin for one, means "being the only one of a kind", does it need to change ***quite unique*** with the only term ***unique*** or, maybe, with the phrase ***almost unique***?

Or, is ***quite unique*** acceptable to use for native English speaker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this phrase is acceptable to native English speakers. One of the meanings of **quite** is *to the greatest possible degree*, therefore it can be used with a non-gradable adjective like **unique**. Other examples are *quite delicious* or *quite amazing*. For more information on **quite** and its usage, check [this link](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/quite).

Comment: Do you think that analogues considerations can be made for _**very**_, in the sense that _**very unique**_ is equivalent to _**quite unique**_?

Comment: @Carlo_R.: **Very unique* isn't normally said. *Very* and *quite* are not equivalents, nor are they used in the same way. Check [here](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/very) for information on the usage of *very*.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: The reason most people don't have a problem with *quite unique* is because *quite* there has more the sense of *remarkably* and *definitely*, rather than *very*. So you'll often hear *quite unique*, but you'll rarely hear *very unique*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thank you, FumbleFingers, for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

It really hinges on what they wanted 'unique' to mean.  If they're strictly defining it as 'one of a kind', using *quite* as an adjective seems erroneous because something's either totally different or it isn't -- there are no shades of grey in between.

On the other hand, you could argue that because the event is multifaceted, there are some aspects of the situation which are unique and some that are not - meaning that, overall, the entire situation is *somewhat* unique, or *quite* unique, or *partially* unique.