# Is "very crucial" redundant?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, redundancy, gradability

This came up as a multiple-choice question in an exam. Is using "very crucial" redundant?. . .  or tautology?

Comment: I think this is essentially a duplicate of [Are the rules regarding absolute modifiers too absolute?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44566/). Note that *very crucial* is uncommon, but I don't think that's because it's tautological/redundant - witness the commonplace [absolutely crucial](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=absolutely+crucial&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), which from a pedant's point of view should be far more unacceptable. It's just not a collocation we happen to use much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Tautology* is the inclusion of words that have the same meaning as other words already used. So, *and vital* make the following sentence tautologous:

- Your contribution is crucial and vital

since *crucial* and *vital* are synonymous.

*Redundancy* occurs when a word is used that adds no extra information to the words already used. So the *very* in *very crucial* is redundant because *crucial* already means *very important*.

Comment: Slightly off-topic: Would the "very" when saying something is "very crucial" compared to something else that is merely crucial still be redundant?

Comment: *Crucial* belongs in the same category of non-gradable adjectives as *essential*, *terrible*, *huge*, *superb*. and so on. It is unnecessary to qualify such adjectives with *very* because the words themselves convey the meaning of *very* (important, bad, large, good). It is often a sign of an unsophisticated writer to add qualifiers to such adjectives. In fact, for me, *very crucial* sounds less important than just *crucial*.

Comment: How about the sentence "This is our most crucial task."?

Comment: You can have several crucial tasks, i.e. they are all very important, but there is one that is the most important of all. So, *This is our most crucial task* is perfectly ok, and the *most* adds information that is not inherently conveyed by the word *crucial*. But the *very* in *This is a very crucial task* adds no such extra information, and is therefore redundant.

Comment: I don't think *very* is necessarily redundant here--when you follow *very* by any adjective, whether it be *fat* or *crucial*, you are comparing it to something, perhaps to most of the other items in its category. If it is possible to compare tasks and conclude that one task is more crucial than another, then it is perfectly plausible to use *very* with *crucial* the same as you would use *very* with any other adjective.

Comment: -1, crucial and important do not mean the same thing.  They are related, but not identical.  Something may be important, even very important, without being crucial.

Comment: @jmoreno, My Collins dictionary defines *crucial* as follows: *Something that is **crucial** is extremely important, especially in connection with a particular situation or event in the future.* Nevertheless, my claim is not that *crucial* and *very important* are interchangeable in all contexts, but simply that the *very* in *very crucial* is redundant, even in contexts where *crucial* is better defined as *decisive*; for example, *Then he made a crucial error of judgement.*

Comment: @Shoe: Crucial **implies** importance, importance does not imply crucial. Something can be important, even extermely important, but still not be crucial. Given "It is crucial this arrive on time" vs "It is very crucial..." vs "It is absolutely crucial", if it doesn't arrive on time, it will be hard to recover in the first case, very hard to recover in the second, and probably impossible in the last.

Answer (score 6):

I'll disagree with the other answers here and say that it isn't actually redundant (and is certainly not a tautology).

When you use the word *very* with any adjective, you are communicating that the adjective applies greater than normal to the noun that it modifies. That is, a *very fat man* conveys a higher grade of fatness than just a plain *fat man*. Any adjective that is comparable can be elevated with *very*.

Even words that include such elevation in their definition can be compared: one person can be more terrible than another, one architectual work can be more superb than another, one object can be more huge than another, and, yes, one person can have more unique qualities than another and thus be more unique.

*Crucial* is among these. It is trivial to come up with an example where you can have varying magnitudes of cruciality.

> We are closing in on our deadline and we have many crucial tasks that we need to complete before we ship our product. That said, we have two very crucial tasks that we need to attend to the most.

Admittedly, this may be bad style and it may seem too repetitive to reuse the same adjective, but this is merely a stylistic redundancy issue, rather than a semantic issue.

Comment: Nice job of explaining how _very crucial_ can be used legitimately. It makes me wonder what the testers had to say in their multiple choice exam.

Comment: In the context of a test I would certainly afirm that it is redundant. A test is like a game where you try to guess how the test writer wanted you to answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it is both redundant and a tautology. Another interesting word for it is a:

> ***pleonasm:*** *The use of more words than are required to express an idea; redundancy.*

Comment: I thought "foot pedal" was a pleonasm... Very crucial does not sound like a pleonasm