# Is it correct to use "most" + "-est" together?

Tags: grammar, differences, superlative-degree

I was over exaggerating while writing something for class and I wrote

> Welcome to the **most wildest** show on earth.

Someone pointed out the *most wildest* and I was wondering if it was OK to use ***most*** with a word that ends in ***-est*** together.

Comment: The _over_ was bothering me too :}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "most superior" correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94154/is-most-superior-correct)

Comment: I think "mostest wildest" would be somewhat worse.

Comment: Do this only if you are silently referring to Shakespeare's "most unkindest cut".

Comment: @SvenYargs you mean 'somewhat worser'

Comment: If your intent is to "over-exaggerate" then such constructions are perfectly fine.  It is understood that in such circumstances rigid adherence to "the rules" is not required.

Answer (score 6):

No it is not ok to use more + -er or most + -est, unless you want to sound childish.

[Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting):

> ***Warning***:
> We do not use more or most together with an -er or -est ending:
>
> They emigrate because they are looking for a better life.
> Not: … <s>a more better life</s>
>
> The beach at Marmaris is one of the biggest in Turkey.
> Not: … <s>the most biggest</s> …

Comment: You're telling me that society bigwig [Perle Mesta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perle_Mesta) was not the "Hostess with the Mostest"??

Answer (score 4):

Not "OK". If you want to go "over the top", then it should not be with a grammatical error but rather using extra (or arguably extraneous) adjective(s):

> Welcome to the absolutely, positively wildest show on earth.

I suppose an exception to this rule would be the (now trite) expression “the hostess with the mostest”, but that only because the doggerel rhyme makes it amusing.

Answer (score 0):

If by "class" you mean an English language class, then *‘most wildest’* will probably attract the ire and the red pen of your teacher. If someone exclaims: "It's not grammatical!" he or she probably belongs to the [prescriptivist](https://jacobian.org/writing/descriptivists-and-prescriptivists/) camp. Avoid using two superlatives together if you're writing an English exam or test, examiners will think you do not know how to use the superlative correctly.

Otherwise, in the "real" world of communication such as texts, IM, and casual speech, the rules for [double superlatives](http://grammar.about.com/od/d/g/doublesuperlativeterm.htm) are broken all the time. If someone believes that language is dictated by its speakers and not by grammar books, they are most likely a [descriptivist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description). Yes, there are grammar rules in English, but if one is an able writer, these rules can be broken.

### The *Rule*

> Adjectives and adverbs in the superlative degree are similar to the comparative degree, but use the -est ending and the word “most” instead. In addition, the article “the” must be placed before the adjective or adverb in the sentence. Comparative sentences using the superlative degree are saying that something is the most when compared to the rest of the group.
>
> Consider the following sentence:
>
> 1. Justin **is the fastest** runner on the track team.
>
> Generally speaking, the superlative degree is used when something is being compared to three or more things.
>
> A common mistake with double superlatives is using both the ending -est and the word “most” in the same sentence. Errors with double superlatives can also be identified when the sentence by reading the sentence out loud. For example, the prior sentence would be incorrect if it was written as follows:
>
> 1. “Justin **is the most fastest** runner on the track team.”
>
> It would be best to remove “most” and keep *fastest* in the superlative degree
>
> Source: [*grammarly blog.com*](http://www.grammarly.com/blog/2013/double-comparatives-and-superlatives/)

There is however one exception when two superlatives can be used together, consider "most best actor", it does sound childish but...

> The **most Best Actor nominations** is nine, for both Spencer Tracy and Laurence Olivier (Nicholson has eight). [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_actors_with_two_or_more_Academy_Award_nominations_in_acting_categories)

That example is grammatically acceptable, although rather awkward-sounding. One way to rephrase it, would be:  “The most nominations for ‘Best Actor’ is nine...”

And to show that speakers do commit this type of ‘error’ frequently, we have

> - What is **the most quickest** and painless way to die? [*ask*reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/2r8vdh/what_is_the_most_quickest_and_painless_way_to_die/)
> - **Most Worst** Situations To Be In [*facebook*](https://www.facebook.com/Most-Worst-Situations-To-Be-In-676600989056269/)
> - Hottest and **least hottest** Womens USA soccer team. *[MutHead](http://www.muthead.com/forums/off-topic/sports-discussion/430922-hottest-and-least-hottest-womens-usa-soccer-team)*

The following citations by William Shakespeare will probably quell the protesters methinks.

> PAULINA: What wheels? Racks? Fires? What flaying? Boiling
>   In leads or oils? What old or newer torture
>
> Must I receive, whose every word deserves
>   To taste of thy **most worst**? Thy tyranny,
>   Together working with thy jealousies –
>   Fancies too weak for boys, too green and idle

> CASSIUS: Ay, every man away.
>   Brutus shall lead, and we will grace his heels
>   With **the most boldest and best** hearts of Rome

> This was the **most unkindest** cut of all.

> The line is from Shakespeare's *Julius Caesar*, 1601
>
> ANTHONY: […]
>   For Brutus, as you know, was Caesar's angel:
>   Judge, O you gods, how dearly Caesar loved him!
>   This was the most unkindest cut of all;
>   For when the noble Caesar saw him stab,
>   Ingratitude, more strong than traitors' arms,
>   Quite vanquish'd him: then burst his mighty heart;
>   […]
>
> **Origin**
>
> English teachers would probably put a red line through any schoolchild's text that included the 'most unkindest'. That Del Boy-sounding phrase would be corrected to 'most unkind' or just 'unkindest'. Shakespeare rose far above the concerns of spelling and grammar. As was the manner at the time, he wasn't even interested enough in spelling to be consistent in the spelling of his own name.
>
> Source: [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/396100.html)

Comment: While your special example is fine I don't think it really explains WHY that exception exists. The point being in the sentence you quote, "most" modifies a different noun then "best". Best modifies actor whereas most modifies nominations. So you still don't really get two superlatives being used together instead they are just being used next to each other.

Comment: A bold statement indeed, that Shakespeare could quell the protesters. "The most boldest and best" could very well be "the greatest number of the boldest and best" or "the most, the boldest, and the best". And "the most unkindest" could very well be just a lazy way to achieve iambic pentameter. Methinks it is indeed. And sure, this terrible construction is used all the time, resulting in a lot of childish-sounding English speakers. On the other hand, "the most (best actor) nominations" is completely different, and not childish-sounding or incorrect at all. Perhaps that's what you'd call "able"?

Comment: http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/prescriptivism-and-descriptivism/

Comment: I would "describe" the double superlative construction as terrible-sounding, at the most best of times, and suggesting to a schoolgirl that it's a mark of writing ability as the most misleadingest of comments, particularly in the same breath as "texts" and "IM". ;-)

Comment: @RJH  Here is a list of "terrible-sounding" double comparatives and superlatives by the most noblest bard himself ;) http://www.shakespeareswords.com/Comparison

Comment: I'll take comfort in the first sentence on that page: "There are several interesting differences between the modern system of expressing comparison and the one available to Shakespeare." I'll also take some issue with it, as Shakespeare's English is in the "modern English" period, as it's usually characterized. But I think the fact that Shakespeare was often shoehorning words into a constrained poetic meter shouldn't be overlooked. Context is often key, and what might seem poetic in artificially constrained meter will often seem weirder outside of it.

Comment: But may I also say, that is an interesting list – so, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, it is not what would be considered "correct" grammar. If you are aware of this then in the context of "over exaggerating" for dramatic or comedic effect it might be suitable whereas in serious writing it would not. If you know the rules then you can choose when to break them for effect and when it will make you look stupid.

Answer (score 0):

The superlative adjective 'most' here is used to modify the 2nd adjective 'wildest' which also happens to be written in the superlative; it sounds spontaneous but there is no grammatical error here.

This spontaneity is called cumulative adjectives. They appear side by side but can't separately modify the noun 'show'. EG ' welcome to the **wildest show** on earth' makes sense but ' but ' welcome to the **most show** on earth' does not. In other words, 'wildest show' is a unit and is modified by 'most'.

Comment: I'm not sure you're really answering the question that was asked.

Answer (score -2):

Everything is ok. You have poetic license to write the way you want to express your ideas as you see fit. Don't be constrained by arbitrary rules or negative critics.

Comment: Hi, Teusz, Welcome to EL&U. This community doesn't encourage an answer without reference or research that can support your answer. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.