# "least riskiest" vs "safest" - double superlative or single is better?

Tags: antonyms, superlative-degree

Is "least riskiest" stylistically correct? Can it be considered a double superlative? Would "safest" be a better choice?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it correct to use "most" + "-est" together?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301310/is-it-correct-to-use-most-est-together) Short answer (from the first comment to that question): ***It sounds childish. Do it only for fun, or in order to annoy.***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Least riskiest" makes no sense.

You can, if you wish, apply "least" to an adjective, making the phrase:

> least risky

Although technically the same in meaning as "safest", it has a different implication. Most people will interpret "least risky" to mean that all options are risky, but one option is not as risky as the others. "Safest" is more likely to be used when comparing multiple safe options, to find that which is most safe.