# semantic property shared by words between class of words

Tags: semantics

What semantic property or properties are shared any words in 1 and 2?

1. alive, asleep, dead, married, pregnant
2. tall, smart, interesting, bad, tired

I don't see any shared between those words.

Comment: Have you tried [ell.se]?

Comment: 1: you either are or are not these. 2: you can be a little or a lot of these.

Comment: Mitch has it. List 1 contains binary characteristics, with only two states: yes and no; these parallel count nouns. List 2 contains multi-state gradable characteristics, which can be measured and compared on a cline in at least one semantic dimension; these parallel mass nouns.

Comment: As @Mitch says, the words in the first list are ["absolute modifiers"](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/44566/2637), but not those in the second list.

Comment: Does someone here think they understand the Q and happen to know the answer? Would they be so kind as to help the OP?

Comment: Those who are into database design/ web-design will see this as an excellent question.

Comment: "A **semantic class** contains words that share a semantic property. Semantic classes may intersect. The intersection of *female* and *young* can be *girl*." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_class -- Both your examples can exhibit semantic relations. What exactly is the relation depends on the context. That, incidentally, is outside the purview of language and ELU.

Answer (score 4):

The common thread in set 1 is "state". As in the state of being alive, asleep etc. The common property in set 2 is "quality". They are all adjectives and adjectives qualify nouns. Therefore, "quality" can be determined as the underlying semantic property.

Answer (score -2):

Set 1 is *not gradable*: not to be modified by "very" and without comparative or superlative degree. Set 2 is *gradable*.