# Justification of "more perfect"

Tags: comparatives

I've just read this interesting [article](http://www.jimloy.com/language/perfect.htm).

We were being constantly told back in school years that we couldn't use "more" to modify "perfect".

I kept feeling guilty using "more perfect" until I read the following idea from the article:

> Nothing is perfect. When we say "perfect man", it is an exaggeration.
>   Using "perfect" for things that are not perfect opens the door for
>   "more perfect" and even "most perfect".

This is really a sensible and convincing justification to me. Then I think of other words that our teachers wouldn't allow us to modify using "more". For example, people begin to use "more excellent" fairly frequently nowadays.

However, the use of "more excellent" might not be justified convincingly by the same logic that applies to "more perfect" above. The reason is people can absolutely be excellent while nobody can be perfect. If the justification logic for "more perfect" should fail to hold for "more excellent", what could a sensible way to justify the use of "more excellent"?

Comment: Just to nail my colours to the mast, I have no problem with *most unique*, so I certainly wouldn't take issue with *most perfect*. And *most excellent*, although a bit dated in constructions like *His most excellent majesty*, seems uncontentious to me. But from OP's point of view, surely such usage is either okay because people habitually apply "excellent" to things which aren't truly excellent (same logic as "perfect"), or it's okay because there are degrees of excellence.

Comment: ...and here's my justification for saying [there are degrees of excellence](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=degrees+of+excellence&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: "A More Perfect Union" is the name of a speech delivered by Senator Barack Obama on March 18, 2008 .... and no one would question HIM now that he is President!

Comment: @GEdgar To be fair, that's a quote from the preamble of the United States Constitution: "We, the People, in order to form a more perfect union…"

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question. You already have a justification for "more perfect" that satisfies you; what you want is a justification for "more excellent."

Comment: As Jadasc has pointed out, you should clarify your question, lest you continue getting answers that do not so much as mention the word *excellent*. Also, see [this related question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7595/more-perfect-versus-less-imperfect) first.

Comment: I recall an elementary school teacher telling the class that it was incorrect to say "more equal" because two things are either equal or they are not. I find this totally unconvincing. Any physical measurement, for example, is only an approximation. If Al, Bob, and Charlie are all 6 feet tall, we could say that they are of "equal height". But if a more precise measurement finds that Al is 6.01 feet, Bob is 6.02 feet, and Charlies is 6.08 feet, it is reasonable to say that Al and Bob are "more equal" in height than either is to Charlie.

Comment: @Jay Agree. It seems nothing is absolute. Unfortunately, our schooling tends to teach us rules to follow.

Comment: "More perfect" is always wrong. Those who say nothing is perfect probably never heard of Nadia Comăneci – https://youtu.be/Yl9QpC8_LiE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your meaning: If you mean it in the absolute sense, then no. But if you mean "[Thoroughly skilled or talented in a certain field or area; proficient](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/perfect)", yes, you may say that there are degrees of perfection.

Reminds me of a great W.C. Fields line:

> *Og Oggilby*: Oh... I knew this would happen! I was a perfect idiot to ever listen to you!
>
> *Egbert Sousé*: You listen to me, Og! There's nothing in this world that is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

In actual usage, the word "perfect" has been subject to modifiers ever since it was introduced to the language. The rule that you cannot modify "perfect" is, therefore, contrary to actual established usage. It is an example of hypercorrection.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/perfect

Another construct which sometimes receives unfair criticism is "more optimal".